# Can't get $_SESSION to work

Tags: php, session, authentication, web

I'm making this login system but my site won't see the values I put into `$_SESSION` on another page.

In my header code (which is included on every page) I got:

```
<?php
     session_start(); 
?>
```

and my login processing:

```
<?php

include("header.php");

$myusername= $_POST['naam2']; 
$mypassword= $_POST['wachtwoord']; 

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM winkel WHERE naam='$myusername' AND BINARY wachtwoord ='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1) {
    session_register($myusername);
    $inf = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $_SESSION['winkelinfo'] = $inf;
    header("Location: mijntreinwinkeltje.php");
}
else {
    header("location:login.php?err=1");
}

?>
```

it then redirects to **mijntreinwinkeltje.php** when I fill in the right credentials.
Then in **mijntreinwinkeltje.php** I put:

```
<?php
    include("header.php");
    $winkelinfo = $_SESSION['winkelinfo'];
    if ($winkelinfo)
        echo("derp".$winkelinfo['naam']);
    $voornaam = $winkelinfo['gebruikervoornaam'];
    $achternaam = $winkelinfo['gebruikerachternaam'];

?>
```

But it it would then not print `echo("derp".$winkelinfo['naam']);`
and `$voornaam` and `$achternaam` would both be empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$inf = mysql_fetch_array($result);`what you get in `$inf` use `print_r` or `var_dump` to check.and try not using mysql_fetch_array try using _assoc if you using numeric keys

Comment: I've checked if the variables are legit and they all are. I can even echo $SESSION['winkelinfo'] on the login process page and it would show the correct value. It just won't work on any other page.

Comment: Did you check the error logs? also check the session save directory in the php.ini file and make sure that directory is writable by your webserver

Comment: It says in php.ini:session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session" but i cant even find that directory. I would change that but when i try to overwrite it i can permission denied error. Can i change it using htaccess? If so can any1 tell my how? SInce im no master with htaccess :p

Comment: if you having problem in session i will sugest you to use cookies its also useful also for stateless session and load balancers.and let me work on you stuff also

Comment: Do _not_ use `session_register()`. Read the documentation about it and how to really use sessions.

Comment: I do know how it works, i was just desperate and jammed in anything help sites said.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think the main issue is the execution of the page first page has to executed first to set session.else the next page will not have the session.

for example first page is

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['userName'] = 'Root';

?>
```

and second page

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['userName'])) {
  echo "Your session is running " . $_SESSION['userName'];
}
?>
```

if you directly load second page it willl not work because sessions are not set yet.first execute the first page then the second one and not to use `session_register()`

in my opinion use cookies because its more widely used for stateless sessions.

Comment: Im not entirely sure what i shud change. Also shouldnt it then work after page refresh? (which doesn't work)

Comment: wht you using `session_register($myusername);`??

Comment: i dont know i was just trieng stuff.

Comment: you want yo use `$myusername` the also store it in session like `$_SESSION['userName'] = $myusername;` but do not use `session_register($myusername);` try removing it and try

Comment: removed it, didnt change anything.

Comment: remove `if()` from second page any try